# Parallel charging lead-acid batteries that are at different voltages

Tags: battery-operated, lead-acid

For a project of mine, I'm making a battery pack that disconnects the internal battery after switching to an external battery.

I'm a bit worried about parallel charging lead-acid batteries that are at different voltages.

Doesn't it create big currents between the batteries without the diode? I don't want to waste battery energy charging the internal battery with the external one.

Here below is the schematic. A charger and two batteries automatically switch between each other when external battery is plugged in.

[image: part of the Battery pack 12vdc circuit]

Should I be worried about the currents between the batteries or are there things I'm missing?

EDIT:
I've made a newer schematic and added a relay to bypass diode D2, we run on the internal battery until the external one is plugged in. Whenever the charger is plugged in it bypasses D2 and can charge both batteries battery. imgur.com/a/RQGyYy5

Comment: The parts in parallel are the terminals.  Voltage at terminals vs voltage in cells determines the actual rate you should be concerned about; if the charger is driving it higher than either battery would alone have, the charger is supplying the current.  Lead acid can generally take a bigger unregulated beating in that regard compared to other types but be aware that there are several types of lead acid...

Comment: @Abel As for internal batteries I'm using AGM Batteries and externally a bigger general car battery.  I think in this case It's better to charge the batteries individually right as the tech is different? Then the diodes can be removed and put charger directly behind F1.1.

Comment: Charging thru diodes like that will make the charger think that the batteries' voltage is a diode-drop higher than it actually is - likely resulting in your batteries never being quite as fully topped up as they would be without the diodes.

Comment: @brhans That got me thinking. I've made a newer schematic, we run on the internal battery until the external one is plugged in. Whenever the charger is plugged in it bypasses D2 and can charge both batteries battery. imgur.com/a/RQGyYy5

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't it create big currents between the batteries without the diode?

Without the diodes, yes. Although lead acid batteries are more forgiving of that than lithium-ion batteries, that inrush of current doe degrade the batteries and wastes energy.

With diodes, you prevent current from flowing between batteries. You would need 4 diodes, two between the charger and the two batteries, and two between the batteries and the load. But the diode solution wastes power. And it doesn't work if charging and discharging are through the same connections.

Consider instead using two DC-DC converters, one for each battery. They limit the current between the batteries and do so efficiently.

Or, consider a switch to select one battery or the other. To avoid the short-duration loss of voltage as you're switching, place a large capacitor across the load.

Comment: Hmm, That got me thinking. I've made a newer schematic, 
we run on the internal battery until the external one is plugged in. Whenever the charger is plugged in it bypasses D2 and can charge both batteries battery.
https://imgur.com/a/RQGyYy5